# How to run two python scripts one after another in third python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run two python scripts in the third python script.
The two python scripts got executed simultaneously without waiting for the execution of one script after the other.

I tried `time.sleep(100)` but it's not working.

```
        a1 = "a.py"
        b1 = "b.py"
        python_path = '/opt/dev_ai/bin/python'
        execution = subprocess.Popen([python_path,ml_path+a1,str(rule)])
        time.sleep(100)
        execution=subprocess.Popen([python_path,ml_path+scor+b1,str(rule)])
```

b1 started running before the completion of a1.

Comment: did you try importing them instead of subprocessing?

Comment: You need call [`_ = execution.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: execution.communicate( )    workssss!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return code of the subprocess1 and if it is okay, execute the second subprocess.

[How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run several python files in just one python file you can first;
Keep them in a same file or folder. Next you can type `import 1stfile` then `import 2ndfile` and you can add as many as you want. This only imports python files though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's subprocess starts asynchronous processes, to make this synchronous check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649691/3214029)